# What would be the correct 's if the name ends with an X?

Tags: possessives

Assume someone's name ends with `x`. If we want to refer to one of his belongings, should we say `---x's` or `---x'es`?

The problem here is that if the pronunciation follows spelling.

Comment: A duplicate of the question Peter referred to.

Comment: Not really. they are not the same.

Comment: Is your question about how to pronounce _____x's? And is that the only question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making a word ending with x *plural*, **-es** is added to the end. For example:

> box → boxes
>
> wax → waxes

However, when showing *possession*, which is what you are trying to do here, the regular **-'s** is used:

> The house belonging to Alex → Alex's house.
>
> The shirt belonging to Rex → Rex's shirt.

Comment: but how about when we pronounce it? doesn't it sound like `x'es`?

Comment: Pronunciation would be the same, yes.